# Concatenate a const *char[] variable with a char[]

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm making a connection between C++ and MySql, and I was trying to do something like this:

```
int id=1;
const char *sql = "delete from register where id=";
strcat(*sql, itoa(id));
```

But I can't because `itoa(id)` does not generate a `*char[]` variable.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate onto a string literal. You have to copy the string literal to a separate buffer, and then concatenate onto that. Also, `itoa()` requires a buffer of its own, too:

```
int id = 1;
char sql_buffer[50];
char id_buffer[16];
strcpy(sql_buffer, "delete from register where id=");
strcat(sql_buffer, itoa(id, id_buffer, 10));
```

Or:

```
int id = 1;
char sql_buffer[50] = "delete from register where id=";
char id_buffer[16];
strcat(sql_buffer, itoa(id, id_buffer, 10));
```

Alternatively, use `snprintf()` instead:

```
int id = 1;
char sql_buffer[50];
snprintf(sql_buffer, sizeof(sql_buffer), "delete from register where id=%d", id);
```

But, either way, these are C ways to do things.  The C++ way is to use a `std::ostringstream` instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int id = 1;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "delete from register where id=" << id;
std::string sql = oss.str();
```

Comment: The C way is useful,but I need the final string to stay in the *sql variable. How can I do it? I am trying but I can't

Comment: @JosManuelHernndezIti Your sql variable is constant, which means you can't change it. You can create a new modifiable array that contains the sql command and copy the const string into it.

Answer (score 2):

Double-check the docs for `itoa`. It takes three arguments and will write the value of your number to the string you provide. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

It would be easier to do the following though.

```
char string[MAX_LENGTH];
snprintf(string, MAX_LENGTH-1, "delete from register where id = %d", id);
```